# Time fields in Rails app all getting populated with January 1, 2000, 12:00AM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.8.7

I'm using Time to hold the start and end dates within an events controller I'm working on. However my application is neglecting to submit the Time information, in both test and development environments, both in the browser and in my Rspec tests. A time appears to be getting created, but what's coming back in all my tests around this is consistently 1 January 2000, 12:00 AM.

Can anyone help with identifying the problem?

The following test is failing for a different reason (please don't worry about this bit), but it shows the extent of the problem. The end_time submitted in the test wasn't January 1 2000 12:00AM.

> Failures:
>
> 1) EventsController GET show when signed in if an end date/time
>   (optional fields) have been supplied display for a multi-day
>   event shows an end date
>
> Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("span", :class => "end_time_date",
>          expected following output to contain a Saturday, 01 January 2000 tag:
>
> ```
> ...
> [div class="start"] 
>     Starts:
>     Saturday, 01 January 2000 at 12:00 AM
> [/div]
> [div class="end"]
>     Ends
>     [span class="end_time_time"]
>         12:00 AM
>     [/span]
> [/div]
> ```

The test that's failing above:

> ```
>   describe "display for a multi-day event" do
>
>       before(:each) do
>         # Turn example event into one that spans multiple days.
>         @event.end_time.advance(:days => 2)
>       end  
>
>       it "shows an end date" do
>          get :show, :id => @event
>          @human_friendly_end_date = @event.end_time.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")            
>          response.should have_selector("span", :class => "end_time_date", 
>                         :content => @human_friendly_end_date)
>       end
>
>       it "shows an end time" do
>          get :show, :id => @event
>          @human_friendly_end_time = @event.end_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
>          response.should have_selector("span", :class => "end_time_time", 
>                      :content => @human_friendly_end_time)
>       end
>   end
> ```

The model, where you can see the start_time and end_time attributes are very much accessible, and (in the case of start_date at this point) required:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

    attr_accessible :name, :description, :start_time, :end_time, 
                        :max_attendees, :min_attendees, :event_type_id  

  validates :name, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 4, :maximum => 140 }

  validates :description, :length => { :minimum => 4, :maximum => 1000 }

  validates :start_time, :presence => true

  #validates :end_time, :presence => true

    validates :user_id, :presence => true

end
```

The FactoryGirl event generation seems irrelevant because the same problem is happening within the browser, but I'll include that here too just in case. You can see (from the commented out bits in this) that I've tried hardcoding numbers in for the creation of the dates/times; this didn't fix anything though.

```
Factory.define :event do |event|
  event.name                    "Foo bar"
    event.description             "Yada yada"
    event.association             :user
  week_num = (rand(10) +1)
  day_num = (1+rand(30))
  hour_num = (1+rand(12))
  hours_duration_num = (1+rand(4))
  future_date = week_num.weeks.from_now
  #event.start_time             "2012,8,5,6"
  #event.end_time               "2012,8,5,7"
  event.start_time              "#{future_date.year},#{future_date.month},#{day_num},#{hour_num}"
  event.end_time                "#{future_date.year},#{future_date.month},#{day_num},#{hour_num+hours_duration_num}"
end
```

My migration:

> class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
>
> def self.up
>
> ```
> create_table :events do |t|
>
>   #foreign key first  
>
>   t.references :event_type
>
>   t.integer :user_id
>   t.string :name, :null => false
>   t.text :description, :null => false
>   t.time :start_time, :null => false
>   t.time "end_time"
>   t.timestamps
> end
> ```

Naaaargh! What's goin' on?!

Comment: what does the form that allows the user to set the start/end time look like ?

Comment: I haven't done any work on that part of the controller yet. Just setting things via rspec tests in order to test the get show action.

Comment: The way you're setting up those times in your fixtures is weird - "2012,8,5,6" isn't a valid date format - I'd guess you're just getting the default Time value which is apparently midnight

Comment: Which is MORE than likely, since this is also the first time I've worked with Time (or dates, or datetimes). I'll look into that: thanks!

Comment: You can do Time.new(2012,1,2,3,4,5) but that's very different to Time.new('2012,1,2,3,4,5'). In your factory girl stuff you've already got perfectly good time instances - `event.start_time (future_date + hour_num.hours)` and  `event.end_time ( future_date + (hour_num + hours_duration_num).hours)` should do the trick. And like Michael said, you probably want datetime columns (which map to the ruby Time class)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps due to time fields instead of date fields.

I would try changing:

```
t.time :start_time, :null => false
t.time "end_time"
```

to

```
t.datetime :start_time, :null => false
t.datetime :end_time
```

Comment: I did try that already, to no avail. (I read in another question also that if this was the problem, the time info would at least be getting saved rather than the "12:00 AM" default, even if the date was being neglected.) Just did it again though, and still didn't help. :(